# Subgaussian concentration implies bound on probability density

Tags: real-analysis, probability, inequality, normal-distribution, concentration-of-measure

Very simple question: Suppose $X$ is a subgaussian RV with a density $p_X(x)$. Does this imply any nontrivial upper bounds on $p_X(x)$ for large $x$?

Some context: It is not hard to show that bounds like $p_X(x)\le e^{-x^2}$ imply subgaussianity. I am wondering about the converse, or can the density of a subgaussian RV be arbitrarily bad?

Note: The example of a bounded, constant RV shows that such upper bounds can only hold for sufficiently large $x$.

Comment: The converse is false. Let $\varphi(x) = \max\{1-|x|, 0\}$ i.e. the "tent function". Consider the density $$p(x) = Z^{-1}\sum_{n \geq 0} \mathrm{e}^n\varphi\left(\mathrm{e}^{n^2+n}(x+n)\right), \quad Z = \sum_{n\geq 0} \mathrm{e}^{-n^2}.$$ The density $p$ has subgaussian tails, but density takes arbitrarily large values.

Comment: @Shiva Would you be willing to provide some explanation in an answer? I think I see what you are trying to do, but a density cannot take on arbitrarily large values for arbitrarily large $x$. It is also not clear to me why this is subgaussian. I am happy to accept this answer with (at least a sketch of) a proof + explanation.